# Pivot table From Association belongs_to - has_many in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This may be a stupid question but im just starting to learn Rail thats why i am asking this question.

I have two models :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :totalsolds
end

class Totalsold < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :qty, :product_id, :product_attributes
  belongs_to :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
end
```

Record of product looks like :

[image: record of product]

Record of totalsold looks like :

[image: totalsold]

And on view, I'm trying to display on view looks like :

[image: display on view]

Question : Are there some kind of tutorials or references to solve my case?

**note : I don't know keyword for search on google, if you know please tell me.
If my question is very low quality, I will close or flag this question**

**update**

I found solution using [pivot_table](https://github.com/edjames/pivot_table), But I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw the following into a seeds.rb file (for a quick and dirty). You can run it from the command-line with rake db:seed

```
a = Product.create! name: 'Product A'
b = Product.create! name: 'Product B'
c = Product.create! name: 'Product C'

Totalsold.create! date: "2014/02/05", product: a, qty: 31
Totalsold.create! date: "2014/02/05", product: b, qty: 12
Totalsold.create! date: "2014/02/05", product: c, qty: 7
Totalsold.create! date: "2014/03/05", product: a, qty: 23
Totalsold.create! date: "2014/03/05", product: b, qty: 16
Totalsold.create! date: "2014/03/05", product: c, qty: 2

pivot_table = Totalsold.includes(:product).group_by &:date
puts pivot_table

pivot_table.each do |date, products|
  puts "Date: #{date}" 
  puts "Products: "
  products.each { |prod| puts "#{prod.product.name} #{prod.qty}"} 
end
```

This does not require the use of any non-rails gems. Basically, you are selecting all totalsolds items (making sure to also include the product information, which you have mapped on the model with belongs_to). Then, when the results come back, you can use ruby's group_by http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by to group the records by date into a Hash.

Answer (score 1):

First two tables are simple forms for `Product` and `TotalSold`. An entry in `TotalSold` indicates a transaction of a *particular* product in *x* quantity on particular day.

The main thing in this question is to generate the table as in Figure 3. This involves few joins and grouping:

- Initially, group on date.
- Group on product.
- sum(quantity)

I can't give the query correct shot, but this may help:

```
TotalSold.select('created_at, product_id, sum(quantity) as sum').group([:created_at, :product_id])
```

You can then map this to generate the table.

Hope this helps :)