# Sum and Multiple Group by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424705/pivot-table-from-association-belongs-to-has-many-in-rails) to display records and successfully display looks like :

[image: views]

And then, I try to add `store` model with attribute `name` , so relationship my models are :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :totalsolds
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :totalsolds
end

class Totalsold < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :nomor ,:qty, :product_id, :store_id, :product_attributes, :store_attributes
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store
end
```

controller :

```
@totalsolds = Totalsold.by_month(field: "date").includes(:product).group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store, s.nomor] }
```

view :

```
<% @totalsolds.each do |(date, store, nomor), totalsold| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
      <td><%= nomor %></td>
      <td><%= Store.find(store).name %></td>
        <% totalsold.each do |prod| %>
          <td><%= prod.qty %></td> 
        <% end %>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

And my record tables looks like :

[image]

I want to display `totalsold` such as :

[image]

**problem when to create totalsolds with same date, nomor and store, qty not calculation. :**

[image]

Comment: Post your `by_month` method in `Totalsold` model.

Comment: `by_month` from [by_star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) gems, I use it.